# Anti Forgery validation not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I know I am missing somthing but It is not working and I don't know what's wrong. here is the custom Anti forgery attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenOnAllPosts : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        //  Only validate POSTs
        if (request.HttpMethod == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)
        {
            //  Ajax POSTs and normal form posts have to be treated differently when it comes
            //  to validating the AntiForgeryToken
            if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];

                var cookieValue = antiForgeryCookie != null
                    ? antiForgeryCookie.Value
                    : null;

                AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
            }
            else
            {
                new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute()
                    .OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am sending the token from ajax request.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/JSON; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/json, */*");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "__RequestVerificationToken token=\"FuHCLyY46\"");
        }
```

And In Asp Master Page I've put the hidden field.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="FuHCLyY46"/>

</div>

</form>
```

But it is not working. please Identify what's wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `__RequestVerificationToken` request header which is what you are attempting to read here:

```
AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
```

The actual header you are sending is called `Authorization`. So you could use a dedicated header that will send the token value:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("AntiForgeryToken", "FuHCLyY46");
```

and then:

```
AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, request.Headers["AntiForgeryToken"]);
```

Comment: I am Exhausted applying Anti forgery in my scenario. actually I am Implementing security in the project in which asp pages (not Rajor) are used. I don't have idea how to implement it in asp forms.

Answer (score -1):

Why you do not use default framework anti forgery action filter and relative Html Helper?
Do not fight the framework :)

More info on CSRF [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/)

Comment: He cannot use this method.  He is using Classic ASP.NET not MVC.  Solution by Darin is correct in his case.